# ¿Cómo crear una ruta general para todos los modelos?

Tags: php, javascript, yii

Tengo un proyecto de *PHP* y *Javascript* con *Yii 1.1*, y el problema es con la *URL* al filtrar una búsqueda tras una ordenación por columna en un *CRUD* en un módulo concreto. No me permite cambiar la búsqueda, mantiene los valores anteriores. Leyendo encontré que la solución radicaba en el *urlManager*:

```
'rules'=>array(
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),
```

¿Cómo podría formar un rule general para que me coja varios módulos?

Answer (score 1):

si no especificas un módulo en las rules, 
ej:

```
rules => array(
  ...
  '<module:nombreModulo>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/view',
  ...
),
```

las rules se aplican a todos los módulos

si quieres para varios módulos pero no todos, puedes usar algo como:

```
rules => array(
  ...
  '<module:(nombreModulo1|nombreModulo2)>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/view',
  ...
),
```

pero para responder bien, necesito más datos de tu caso: url original, url filtrada, nombre modulo, controlador y action